# Delete corresponding values with different Keys from Dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, del

I am new to python and I am writing Flight Booking system program .I got stuck up on delete while deleting the passenger details because I have Dictionary with multiple Keys and the values for the Keys are in separate individual List.

I tried multiple ways using pop function it is deleting only particular Key and the corresponding values

How to delete the all the values of the Passenger Detail with Different Keys.

for eg: is the user enter 'tes' then I need to delete corresponding flightId,Age,destination,dlytype,source

I am getting  User input as below

```
   Passenger = raw_input("Enter Name to delete")
```

Dictionary value shows as below:

```
  {'Passenger': ['tes', 'ssss'],
  'FlightId': ['ssss', 'tre'],
   'Age': ['12', '34'], 
    'Destination': ['ssss', 'ssssss'],
    'Flytype': ['economy', 'business'],
   'Source': ['sss', 'sssss']}
```

Dictionary declared:

```
          Name_list=[]
          Age_list=[]
          Source_list=[]
          Destination_list=[]
          Flytype_list=[]
          FlightId_list=[]

     Passenger_dict= {'Passenger':Name_list,
            'Age':Age_list,
            'Source':Source_list,
            'Destination':Destination_list,
            'Flytype':Flytype_list,'FlightId':FlightId_list}
```

Please help on this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better data structure to store you data will be `list` of `dict`s where each dict will represent one passenger object. (Or, if something is unique for passenger, like *passenger_id*, use that to create dict of dicts with `passenger_id` as key of your main dict)

However, in your current data structure, you can do something like this:

- **Step 1:** Get index of passenger based on `Passenger`. It will raise `ValueError` exception if `name` not found in the list

  ```
  passenger_index = Passenger_dict['Passenger'].index(Passenger)
  ```
- **Step 2:** Delete element at `passenger_index` index from all the lists

  ```
   for v in Passenger_dict.values():
       del v[passenger_index]
  ```